# Narrow "Tasks" scope in Eclipse to single Path for TODOs, FIXMEs, etc

Tags: java, eclipse, task

I'd like to narrow task results in the Eclipse "Tasks" view to the class that I have open. Right now it's showing all tasks for the project.

So for example, if Foo.java is open, only TODOs, FIXMEs, and XXXs will show in the "Tasks" view for that class.

Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the up right corner of the "task" tab, you have a little menu. You can use **Configure Contents** in this menu to choose which tasks you want to display.